# Reproducible research and corporate identity

Tags: copyright, creative-commons

My university is on a drive to unify its corporate identity (it makes me sick just typing that). This drive includes branding our lecture slides, research talks, and research posters. The branding templates are not released under an open license and utilize a copyrighted logo and proprietary fonts. I think this prevents me from releasing my talks and posters under a free and open license (e.g., [CC BY](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/)) which is one of the tenets of [Reproducible Research](http://www.rrplanet.com/).

Apart from creating two versions of everything, is there any way to reconcile this apparent incompatibility?

Is my understanding of licenses like [CC BY](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/) wrong? Can I release something (e.g., a research talk or poster) with a copyrighted logo that I don't hold the copyright on under a free and open license?

Comment: Have you contacted the division of your university responsible for copyright (Library, Division IP) regarding their licensing of their copyright material and their font licence for reproduction on CC BY?  Their own licences may be such to allow you to do so.

Comment: @SamuelRussell not yet, I am still trying to track them down. As far as I can tell no one wants to take responsibility.

Comment: Maybe you could specify "everything except the logo and fonts is released under a CC BY license"?  Strictly speaking, that would be fairly restrictive, since it would not give people permission to redistribute the file as is.  However, it would at least make it clear what is available for reuse if that's the aspect you are worried about.  I imagine your university would even agree to a more elaborate license (saying the whole file is distributable without modifications under CC BY-ND and everything but the logo and fonts can be reused under CC BY), which might be the closest to what you want.

Comment: Regarding the logo the university might agree to CC BY because it forbids reusing anything "in any way that suggests that they endorse you or your use of the work".  One could argue that a logo automatically implies endorsement and therefore cannot be reused even if taken from a CC BY licensed work, in which case including it in such a work shouldn't be a problem.  However, I'm sure the university would want to discuss this with their lawyers before deciding that clause made it safe.  In any case, you are right that because you don't hold the copyright, you need their explicit permission.

Comment: What does capitalised "Reproducible Research" mean? Please can you add an explanation to the question? It must mean something different to uncapitalised "reproducible research", because that wouldn't require talks and posters to be released under a free and open licence at all, so I guess you're talking about something more institutionalised and ideological?

Comment: @EnergyNumbers I added a link to http://www.rrplanet.com/. The idea of capital Reproducible Research is that in the absence of free and open licensing (among many other steps) research isn't easily reproducible.

Comment: _This drive includes branding our lecture slides, research talks, and research posters._ — Just say no.  Actually, don't even say no.  **Just don't do it.**

Comment: @JeffE talks are easy. Posters, and to an extent lecture handouts, need to be printed. The university approved printer won't print I branded material.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My university has had enforced its "corporate identity" since the 1990s. It is described in details on a web site and available in a series of templates. Although I get a sense of tiredness when I read the material surrounding the "identity" I can also see benefits, to recognize the university "products" (sorry) among other materials at a congress etc. But, the question was about reproducing material.

As I see it I would want to have the logo on material such as posters or presentations so that people can identify my affiliation. I am free to post presentations and posters or other materials on my university site with the logos on them. If I want to put some material out that is mine I simply would not use a unversity logo. An example: I have written several hopefully useful booklets on scientific writing to be used by students. This material is my initiative and is not the result of the university asking for it. These booklets are distributed for free using our web-page and I would gladly distribute them more widely if there was demand. So from this perspective I can see two different "products" where one benefits from the logo and one where I do not want it.

Now the rules of my university says the logo is copyrighted which means others cannot use it. this still means I can post material with the logo in public places. The problem arises if someone takes my, say, presentation and uses it as their own. Then they break the copyright and make themselves guilty of a kind of fraud by associating themselves with an organisation to which they do not belong. I still have done nothing wrong, posting material is fine and even encouraged. The copyright also prevents people from the taking the university logo and adding it to their own "product" fo rexample showing it on their web-page or using it for commercial uses.

So now, the content. You seem to indicate that you will be prevented from displaying your work without the branding. I do not think this is correct. The laws on copyright and particulary intellectual ownership in my country is very clear. If you have created something it is yours. In a commercial company you may end up sign off this right by becoming employed so that the things your develop within that company belongs to them, not you. That is how research in pharmaceutical companies work, for example. My university system has made attempts to gain rights to lectures etc. but this has so far failed miserably due to the strong laws. You need to check these laws that apply to you since I do not know how they may vary internationally; I would expect them to look fairly similar.

You mention "proprietary fonts". This means the university has selected fonts and bought them from a font foundry so that you can use and copy them for free within the university system. This does not mean other cannot use them, they must simply buy them first so providing copies to persons outside of your university would be illegal. Since fonts are not included in Office templates or in pedfs resulting from your templates there is nothing illegal about distributing such documents. If you were to take the fonts and produce a product that you were to sell for your won personal gain, you will, however, break the law.

The bottom line, then, is that you can put your  material in the creative commons as long as you avoid the logo (ater all who would want to use a figure with somebody elses logo in it?). I cannot see the university preventing you from doing this unless they explicitly ask you to waive your rights. Material with logo has its place when you want to make sure your afficilaition is clear. If you do not want that, then I believe you are free to post things in another style.

Finally awareness of the laws and regulations concerning intellectual rights are important and I strongly believe it is good to carefully look at whatever applies in each of our cases so that we can react if someone tries to infringe on such rights.

Comment: +1. very nice answer. I think that nothing prevents the OP from posting his materials online. If its about research communication as the OP indicates, it will do the job. Others can use the content without the fonts, logos etc.

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion is to follow your school's guidance as much as you have to, but figure out a way to remove (by script, macro, by hand, or otherwise) the branding for distribution.  Have both versions available on your website.  If you have a presentation that you may want to distribute, put a note at the bottom of the title slide, or at the end:

> A freely distributable version of this presentation is available here: [web address].

If your branding mechanism is a master/template slide, it is trivial to remove this for a non-branded version.  I have a hard time believing that printing issues (for posters or handouts) should be a big concern for redistribution -- if it isn't digital, very few people are going to scan/copy for redistribution anyway.

Comment: This is the two version approach that I was hoping to avoid. Having gaps where a logo once was will look a little odd. Changing the type face may cause the text to reflow/change size requiring a new layout.

Comment: @DanielE.Shub My fault -- I didn't properly read that you wanted to avoid the two versions.  When it comes down to it, though, how do you want people to share the work?  Do you want the ideas shared, or the actual document?  If it is the former, it doesn't really matter what the document looks like.  I would absolutely avoid branding individual graphs or charts. As for the font issue -- unless your school is using a really odd-ball font, you should be able to find a suitable free replacement without much trouble.