# Using materials from a CC-BY-licensed poster with logos

Tags: publications, graphics, online-resource, poster, creative-commons

I would like to borrow a *figure* (likely as is) and/or a stylized *table* (likely adapted) to use in a survey research paper, to which I'm contributing my part(s) as one of co-authors (those materials nicely summarize the trends of the subject matter). The source, from which I want to borrow the above-mentioned materials is a *poster*, licensed under **CC-BY** and shared on `figshare` (). According to the [CC-BY license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0), it seems that there should be no problems whatsoever, given that I will follow the terms of the license. Specifically, I plan to properly cite the materials (including DOI) as well as make a note, specifying which one is adapted, if any. *Is there anything else I should keep in mind?*

Also, the CC-BY license "stamp" on the poster states that *companies'/products'/projects'* **logos** on the diagram are not covered by the license (obviously!). So, in this case, I assume that I should either include the same note or a statement along the lines of "logos of companies, products or projects are the property of their representative owners", which seems like a valid case of *fair use*.

Comment: I'm a little confused: are you just using the poster wholesale, including all the logos, or are you pulling you a part that doesn't include the logos? If you are using the logos, what role do they play in the image?

Comment: Possibly related http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/10481/reproducible-research-and-corporate-identity

Comment: @StrongBad: Thank you for the link (+1) - that discussion is quite relevant.

Comment: @jakebeal: Neither one of the options you've mentioned. I'm considering using one or two parts of the 3-parts poster, and one of those two parts is a diagram, containing logos (circular diagram - see below). Specifically, this is the poster in question: http://dx.doi.org/10.6084/m9.figshare.1286826. Actually, I don't like the circular diagram much and, if I'd have time and all logos in source form, I'd consider transforming it into more traditional diagram with time dimension on x-axis and an additional benefit of all logos and phase names being placed horizontally for improved readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Addition to the citation, you should give the exact copyright information of your source below the figure and table you (remixed and) reused.

For your [source](http://dx.doi.org/10.6084/m9.figshare.1286826) you should give: `CC-BY-SA, all logos excluded`.

Please note that the license is [CC-BY-SA](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) and not [CC-BY](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/). Even so CC-BY is given on the web page, the poster says CC-BY-SA. The SA means:

> ShareAlike — If you remix, transform, or build upon the material, you must distribute your contributions under the same license as the original.

In other words, if you remix the figure and table, you have to publish under the same license, i.e. CC-BY-SA.

Comment: I ended up not including the content in question into my paper, however it is always good to know the right approach for the future. Thus, it's a good answer - thank you for clarifications. Upvoting and accepting.